# Using which() on POSIXct object grabs wrong elements

Tags: r, date, datetime, posix, posixct

I have a data frame, e, that has a Date column. In the original file, the dates are saved as factors. So I convert them to character strings. In those strings, they are in the format Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute, e.g. 27/05/2014 15:42. I then use strptime to convert these strings to POSIXct objects.

```
e$Date = as.character(e$Date)
e$Date = strptime(e$Date, tz = "UTC",  format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

All looks good in the output because the dates now are in the form "2014-05-27 15:42:00 UTC". However. When I use which() to find the dates after "2016-02-14 00:51:00 UTC", I get the wrong dates!

```
 which(e$Date>"2016-02-14 00:51:00 UTC")
```

The command returns a list of dates that start with "2016-02-12 08:54:00 UTC" even though there are several dozen dates after my start point, but before "2016-02-12 08:54:00 UTC" that it does not include. It seems to be shifted ahead by 8 or 9 hours.

I know I'm doing something wrong with the timezones. I saw the answer on [Subset dataframe based on POSIXct date and time greater than datetime using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880823/subset-dataframe-based-on-posixct-date-and-time-greater-than-datetime-using-dply) which seemed really close to my problem. However, I did specify the timezone in my original strptime command (I've also tried using as.POSIXct instead of strptime and have the same problem).
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably keep it as a `POSIXlt` datetime (which `strptime` creates), and then compare against another datetime object in the appropriate timezone. E.g.:

```
x <- strptime(c("2018-08-30 08:04", "2018-08-30 08:05", "2018-08-30 08:06", 
"2018-08-30 08:07", "2018-08-30 08:08"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")
#[1] "2018-08-30 08:04:00 UTC" "2018-08-30 08:05:00 UTC"
#[3] "2018-08-30 08:06:00 UTC" "2018-08-30 08:07:00 UTC"
#[5] "2018-08-30 08:08:00 UTC"
```

Text comparison gives odd results:

```
x > "2018-08-30 08:06:00 UTC"
#TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Datetime comparison:

```
x > as.POSIXlt("2018-08-30 08:06:00", tz="UTC")
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```